# Can a List<t> be accessed by multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am planning to share a List between multiple threads. The list will be locked during a changes, which happen infrequently. Is there a thread safety issue if multiple iterations are made from different threads through the list simultaneously?

Comment: If the list is locked properly, then what sorts of issue could there possibly be?

Comment: You can't lock a list, you can only block code.  Have all code that accesses the list (or its element objects) enter a lock statement that uses a private object to keep the lock state.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can (if you can use .NET 4 that is), use [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx):

> Provides blocking and bounding capabilities for thread-safe collections that implement `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`.

If not then encapsulate the list completely and add thread-safe methods that access the `List<T>'s` state.  Don't make the reference to the list public or return it from any methods - always encapsulate the reference so you can guarantee that you are locking around all access to it.

Comment: Is there a cost to using BlockingCollection<T>?

Comment: @Behrooz : No more cost than a custom wrapper around `List<T>` that implements the same locking logic.  As to exactly *how* much overhead it adds over `List<T>` I cannot say.

Comment: I'm surprised that this answer was accepted.  The default behavior of `BlockingCollection` is a queue rather than a list.  There's no way to access it by index and there's no way to iterate over it without removing items.  I guess the OP really needed a queue.

Comment: Default id queue, but you can replace it with whatever you want.

Answer (score 8):

A [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is not a thread-safe class but if you lock everytime you read/write to it there won't be any issues. According to the documentation:

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic)
>   members of this type are thread safe.
>   Any instance members are not
>   guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> A `List<T>` can support multiple readers
>   concurrently, as long as the
>   collection is not modified.
>   Enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. In the rare case where an
>   enumeration contends with one or more
>   write accesses, the only way to ensure
>   thread safety is to lock the
>   collection during the entire
>   enumeration. To allow the collection
>   to be accessed by multiple threads for
>   reading and writing, you must
>   implement your own synchronization.

Answer (score 8):

`List<T>` is not thread-safe generally. Having multiple readers will not cause any issues, however, you cannot write to the list while it is being read. So you would need to lock on both read and write or use something like a `System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock` (which allows multiple readers but only one writer).

Comment: There is almost never a case to prefer `ReaderWriterLock` over `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.  The `Slim` version performs better and has a much better API.

Comment: True, but `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is only available in v3.5+ as it is in `System.Core.dll`. `ReaderWriterLock` is available from v1.1+ and is in the `mscorlib`. I unfortunately am forced to work with a lot of .Net 2.0 code, so I have no choice in the matter.

Answer (score 3):

It can be *read* from multiple threads simultaneously, if that's what you're asking. Consider a reader-writer lock if so.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question you have to take a look first to the documentation, then to the source code and there is a **warning** at this place - the source code of `List<T>` can be modified through the years.

*Darin Dimitrov* has quoted the documentation from year 2010 and there is a differences to the year 2021:

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread
> safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but
> issues can occur if the collection is modified while it's being read.
> To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write
> operation. To enable a collection to be accessed by multiple threads
> for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.
> For collections with built-in synchronization, see the classes in the
> System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. For an inherently thread-safe
> alternative, see the ImmutableList class.

As you can see there is already no such a sentence

> Enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe
> procedure

So an advice is - **check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) and [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) of `List<T>` and track changes on .NET framework**.

The answer to your question is - **it depends**.

If you use `foreach` to iterate through the list, then if the list was modified, even just call `list[i]=value`, where the `value` is equal to `list[i]`, you will become an exception, since the `List<T>._version`(which will be checked by the enumerator object) being changed on set.

`for` loop at this place will not throw an exception, if you will modify a value in the list, but change on the length of the list can be dangerous.

**If the list will not be modified at all during the iterating**, then the iterating is thread safe.

Comment: I believe that the reason they removed the *"Enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure"* statement is because it is refuted by the mere existence of the immutable collections. Nothing actually changed with the `List<T>` type itself, since the Darin Dimitrov's 2010 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4504360/11178549).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Search in implementation for `BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5`

Comment: This suggests that the `ForEach` method was inconsistent with the standard `foreach` enumeration before .NET 4.5, and they fixed it by making the `ForEach` behave exactly like the `foreach`. The `foreach` itself stayed the same. Btw it is quite easy to enumerate a `List<T>` without the `_version` check, if that's what you want: `foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count).Select(i => list[i])) {...`. But this does not make the enumeration thread-safe. It only makes it version-agnostic.

Comment: I just wanted to say, that there were changes and they can occur in the future, therefore an advice to inspect the implementation.

Comment: Rekshino inspecting the source code can certainly provide some insights about the developers' intentions. But foreseeing the changes that may occur in the future is a stretch. My opinion is that we shouldn't expect any major changes in the core functionality and characteristics of such a popular component like the `List<T>` in the next 100 years. Microsoft has shown that it's very conservative when it comes to preserving backward compatibility of existing APIs, especially when they are known to be widely used.