# C# calling api in loop over calling api using thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am stuck into the problem. I have a API and i have to call it multiple times in a loop. Get the API response of all iteration in a IList. And i have to perform some operation on that IList. I am calling my API in a loop. so let suppose there are 5 iteration of loop. every time when one hit goes to API it waits for its response then perfrom the other one. I want to write those calls in a thread. get the response of all thread at the end. Then perfrom my business logic on that response.

My dummy code is like.

```
                    foreach (..... )
                    {
                       //want to open thread here
                       mylist.Add(CalltoAPI(Params));
                    }
                //want to wait for all thread to be closed.
                   PerformBusinessLogic(mylist);
```

Comment: this is too broad of a question... pls describe further the behavior of that api call, such as is this a web call, the avg duration of it and etc

Comment: This is exactly what Microsoft's Reactive Framework is designed to do.  You'll end up with a query like: `from x in mylist.ToObservable() from y in Observable.Start(() => CalltoAPI(x)) from z in Observable.Start(() => PerformBusinessLogic(x, y)) select z`. That is all multi-threaded. The nice thing is that when you subscribe to the query you can get values back as they are produced and not at the end. It's extremely clean.

Comment: @Leonardo - Why is this too broad? It would be nice to have proper signatures, etc, but it seems like a simple scenario to me. I've voted to re-open.

Comment: @Enigmativity i didn't vote to close, but my answer would change a lot if he told me that the API call is a local dll on a winforms app rather than a facebook like app... depending on the fine details of this, i would not recommend parallelization at all! what if this is massively used part of the code? opening new threads could impose a great performance bottleneck instead of speeding things up...

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track:

you create a list of tasks and add them. Then you can wait for them.

```
var mylist = new List<Task>;
foreach (..... )
{
    //want to open thread here
    mylist.Add(CalltoAPIAsync(Params)); <== this should be an async task method
}
await Task.WhenAll(myList);
```

then you can iterate through your tasks.

Give it a go!

edit: code bit completer:

```
public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        var ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);
        var myList = new List<Task<string>>();
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            myList.Add(CallApiAsync(id.ToString()));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(myList);

        foreach (var task in myList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
        }
    }


    public Task<string> CallApi(string id)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => id);
    }
```

not sure about the task.Result, out of my head- but you get the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to find the best answer here as it greatly depends on particular details like caller application type (console, asp.net, winform, ...) max number of iteration, the performance of called API, ...

All in all, parallel (multithread) programming is tricky and I would recommend to study it deeper.

However, given the amount of information given I would recommend this:

```
var myConcurentlist = new ConcurentBag<CallToApiReturnType>();
Parallel.ForEach(allApiCallsArgs, (oneApiCallArgs) => 
{
    myConcurentlist.Add(CalltoAPI(Params));
});
mylist = myConcurentlist.ToList();
```

Please note that you shall not work with mylist directly as List is unsafe to be used concurrently from multiple threads as stated for example here [Can a List<t> be accessed by multiple threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504335/can-a-listt-be-accessed-by-multiple-threads)