# StateHasChanged not updating on Blazor server app

Tags: razor, blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a Blazor Server app over a SignalR connection with an ASP.NET Core API, this code works fine in WebAssembly but for some reason it doesn't works in Blazor Server app.

I suspect the problem is that `StateHasChanged()` isn't making effect, since             `Console.WriteLine($"Company Name: {item.CompanyName}, Volumn: {item.Volume}");` is printing in console but `MarketData` isn't updating UI at `StateHasChanged()`.

For more context; full code is explained here:

https://www.webnethelper.com/2022/01/aspnet-core-6-signalr-creating-real.html

But I guess it's just a common fix; but I can't find the solution.

I've also tried with `InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());` as mentioned here in stackoverflow but It didnt work. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

```
private HubConnection? hubConn;
private string? ConnectionStatusMessage;
public List<Market> MarketData = new List<Market>(); 
public List<Market> MarketReceivedData = new List<Market>(); 


private  List<string> xSource;
private  List<int> ySource;
private List<object> source; 

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

    xSource = new List<string>();
    ySource = new List<int>();
    source = new List<object>();  

    await service.GetMarketEndpoint();
    await Start();
     
}


private async Task Start()
{
    hubConn = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("https://localhost:7193/marketdata").Build();
    await hubConn.StartAsync();
    if(hubConn.State == HubConnectionState.Connected )
        ConnectionStatusMessage = "Connection is established Successfully...";
    else
        ConnectionStatusMessage = "Connection is not established...";
}

private void MarketDataListener(string chartType)
{
    hubConn.On<List<Market>>("SendMarketStatusData", async (data) =>
    {
        MarketData = new List<Market>(); 
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Company Name: {item.CompanyName}, Volumn: {item.Volume}");
            xSource.Add(item.CompanyName);
            ySource.Add(item.Volume);
        }


        source.Add(ySource);
        source.Add(xSource);


        MarketData = data;

        StateHasChanged();

        await js.InvokeAsync<object>(chartType, source.ToArray());
        xSource.Clear();
        ySource.Clear();
    });
}

private void ReceivedMarketDataListener()
{
    hubConn.On<List<Market>>("CommunicateMarketData", (data) =>
    {
        MarketReceivedData = data;
        StateHasChanged();           
    });
}



public async Task Dispose()
{
    await hubConn.DisposeAsync();
}


async Task  generateLineChartTask()
{
    MarketDataListener("marketLineChart");
     ReceivedMarketDataListener();
    await service.GetMarketDataAsync();
}
 async Task   generateBarChartTask()
{
  MarketDataListener("marketBarChart"); 
   ReceivedMarketDataListener();
    await service.GetMarketDataAsync();
}
```

Comment: It should ineed be `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`.  But with Blazor Serever there might be other Thread related issues. Take a look in the JS Console for errors.

Comment: Be clear about: does the Chart show?

Comment: @HH now works with InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged), thanks; sometimes it is complex to describe the problem when there are so many factors in the air. Like signalr, events, blazor itself; ... and little details between web assembly and web server that you assume they work the same way, but logically they don't. Thank you. If you want, comment on the solution in the answers section; and I give it to you as valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference here is that Blazor Serverside is multithreaded so the callbacks from the circuit will execute on a different Thread.

`StateHasChanged()` has to be executed on the main (UI) thread so call it like   `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`, which is short for `InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged())`.

And be aware of other threading risks. Ie, don't share data like Lists between threads.

Comment: `And be aware of other threading risks. Ie, don't share data like Lists between threads` Can you explain it more, please?

Comment: @AlirezaK : No, "multithreading risks" can fill entire books. I already added one (likely) example but there is so much more that could go wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an example for `don't share lists between threads` on the web?(I am only asking to investigate this issue further in my project.)

Comment: Here is one link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4504335/60761